# What are typical atomic densities of solids and gases?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, atoms, estimation, density

What are average values for the number of atoms per cubic cm for typical solids and gasses at atmospheric pressure?

Answer (score 1):

For any solid or gas, divide the density by the mass of one atom.

So, take the density per cubic centimeter and continue.